# Rails dependency missing for Gibbon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependencies, bundle, gibbon

I'm trying to install Gibon for my rails 3 app. Gibbon needs `multi_json 1.3.4`, so I set it in my gemfile as following:

**Gemfile.rb**

```
# Mail
gem 'multi_json', '1.3.4' # Dependency for gibbon
gem 'gibbon', git: 'git://github.com/amro/gibbon.git'
```

I got this error while bundling:

`Bundle install`

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.1.10) ruby depends on
      multi_json (< 1.3, >= 1.0) ruby

    multi_json (1.3.4)
```

I don't know what to do now, it seems that it is a rails dependency, and it would probably be bothersome to upgrade rails directly for I got a big app.

Comment: Gibbon needs `dump` introduced in MultiJSON [1.3.0](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130), you'll have to upgrade to Rails 4

Comment: Thanks anyways, I upgraded Rails to 3.2 and Gibbon seems to be working. Is it right like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by forcefully upgrading to Rails 3.2, and I got rid of the issue.